# mule-3.3.1 and log4j-1.2-api bridge causes infinite recursion - How to fix?

Tags: java, log4j, mule, stack-overflow, mule-esb

I've got an application running in mule-3.3.1 which itself uses log4j-version 1.
My task is to upgrade all usages of old log4j in our applications.

I replaced the log4j-1*.jar by log4j2 jar files (api, core and the bridge) and
set the properties needed to use old "log4j.properties".

Now, on startup it crashes with a java.lang.StackOverflowError, and the
repeating block of the stacktrace is as follows:

```
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.getLoggerRepository(ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.java:62)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository(LogManager.java:171)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:177)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:192)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger.<init>(RootLogger.java:39)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.getLoggerRepository(ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.java:62)
```

The story is: mule's ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.getLoggerRepository() wants to log something, and ends up being called from the log4j-bridge, which uses "invokeinterface" on

`org/apache/log4j/spi/RepositorySelector.getLoggerRepository:()Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/LoggerRepository;`

and the implementing class is exactly `org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mule 3.3.x is not designed to use newer versions of log4j. Newer versions of Mule that received upgraded versions of log4j to fix security vulnerabilities also required additional patches to be able to upgrade the log4j version.

Additionally Mule 3.3 is so old, and in end of life for so many years that it probably contains many other security vulnerabilities in the libraries it uses that upgrading only log4j should be the lesser of your problems.

My recommendation is to just upgrade to an already supported and patched Mule 3.x version like Mule 3.9.5 with the latest security patches.

It would be better to migrate to Mule 4 if you can but the effort may be significantly higher.

Comment: Well, that's what I hoped the bridge would be designed for: to upgrade SW that isn't able to do log4j2 itself.

Comment: I'm a coding-slave...  I do what *they* tell me to do.   They told me to upgrade log4j, and if that turns out impossible, I'd have to tell them "no way without also upgrading mule".    If I tell that, and someone else later says "but it can be made to work with that mule" then my credibility is gone.   So I asked the question here to just increase the confidence about absolute necessity of mule upgrade, or maybe even get to see a trick to get it working with old mule.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can be 100% sure there is no way to do it but it is not documented nor supported by the product and I haven't seen anyone do it without MuleSoft assistance and a supported version. I guess that your organization doesn't care too much for support on a product that has been EOL'd like 7+ years ago.

Comment: Forgot to add, log4j2 is supported only in later Mule 3.x versions.

Comment: In the meantime I found in the description of the bridge:  "They must not access methods and classes internal to the Log4j 1.x implementation such as Appenders, LoggerRepository or ..." - that seems to be a good base to argue for mule upgrade.